# can anime exist in a parallel universe

Tags: alternate-worlds

The Multiverse Theory states that there are might be infinite amount of universes each with different possibilites so is it possible for an anime universe to exist in some universes?

Comment: I don't know if this question belongs here - but yes, in theory, it's possible. You said in your question that there's possibly an infinite amount of universes, which means there's a never-ending amount of possibilities. The question if it's possible for the things that happen in animes to happen in this world is a little different, though.

Comment: The good ol' possible vs probable. Is it possible? (almost) Anything is possible. But is probable that a universe would exist that is EXACTLY like your fave anime? Unlikely.

Comment: @AndreiROM Assuming an infinite number of universes with no overarching pattern in their individual traits, and assuming an anime is perfectly scientifically sound, the probability of a given concept of a universe (no matter how detailed) approaches 1 to the point it's incomprehensibly close to 1. So "unlikely" (assuming the show is scientifically sound) is quite wrong.

Comment: @NexTerren Only mathematically consistent universe can exist, and this why anime wouldn't exist.

Comment: If there are indeed a truly *infinite* number of universes, anything that could ever be possible is not possible, it is guaranteed. Any percentage, no matter how small, multiplied by infinity is infinity. Any probability is guaranteed. Assuming they still follow all the proper laws (thermodynamics et al.)- definitively not possible universes still won't exist, since the law of zero overrides the law of infinity.

Comment: @Delioth That's not true. Take the coin flip example I mention in my answer. The probability of *not* getting heads for one flip is 0.5^1. The probability of *not* getting heads for n flips is 0.5^n. This produces an asymptote function that we can mathematically prove never reaches zero, even as n tends to infinity.

Comment: @NexTerren But it approaches 0 as n approaches infinity. The probability of having gotten heads at least once in that set (representing the 'goal' reality) for n flips as `n->infinity` approaches 1. The more universes there are, the closer our probability gets to 1, leading to the limit `as n->infinity, heads->1` leading to the induction that when n is "at" infinity, heads is at 1. And since with infinite universes we *are* at infinity, we are at 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if a *specific* anime show could exist following the multiverse theory then the answer is "it depends, but in most cases not exactly."

The multiverse theory doesn't give the alternate universe to betray how reality works (a description of which humanity is trying to put together which we call call 'science'). So in the alternate worlds thermodynamics are still thermodynamics. There's no new elements. Molecules still bind in the same manner. Energy is energy, gravity gravity, magnetism magnetism, etc.

I'm not an avid watcher of anime, but some shows aren't terribly realistic with their portrayal of reality (they're "unscientific" and "break the laws of science" if you will). These anime worlds couldn't exist, but some version of them might.

It should also be stated as a side note that an infinite number of universes does not dictate that every possible universe *must* exist; you can flip a fair coin an infinite number of times and theoretically always flip heads. The probability of this happening is so close to zero to be considered zero practically, but it *still is technically not zero.*

So even the concept of a universe that is perfectly sound as far as science can examine may not exist, assuming the multiverse theory is true.

Comment: Multiverse theory OP mentioned is not about randomness, it's about completeness. So the number of universes is not infinite, it is actually finite, but it contains every possible combination. Also infinite number of flips *always* results in expected value.

Comment: @CemKalyoncu Source on the first part? I've never heard it described that way, and a quick tour of Google isn't holding to your completeness concept from any reputable source I see. As to the flip coin, no it does not. The chance of it not flipping the value (heads or tails) after an infinite number of flips is (literally) infinitesimally small, but it still exists as a possibility.

Comment: 1. http://www.dummies.com/education/science/physics/string-theory-level-3-parallel-universes/ 2. infinity is not a number. At infinite number of trials, there are infinite number of heads and infinite number of tails (inf + inf = inf). There is no randomness in infinity.

Comment: @CemKalyoncu Your link is a dead link. Can you doublecheck it? And as to your comment about the infinite number of trials, that's circular reasoning. You're saying you know that it results in the expected value because it results in the expected value. And infinity is not a number, but it's an absolutely valid *concept* used in mathematics. If it wasn't, your "inf + inf = inf" statement, inherently, would be gibberish.

Comment: It is working for me. Search Many worlds interpretation (MWI) and Level 3 parallel universes. For infinite coin tosses: http://www.ee.iitm.ac.in/~krishnaj/EE5110_files/notes/lecture8_Infinite%20Coin%20Toss.pdf